# Using Solve to obtain a constant so that f(x) is continuous at x=2

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, piecewise

[image: Limit of both sides of function]

I need to solve for `c` such that the function is continuous at `x=2`.  How do I do this automatically?

I have expressions for the limit of both sides of the function as x->2, but how would i use the solve command for the value c that makes f(x) continuous at x= 2. would I make both out puts equal each other? Once I get the value of C how do i use the Piecewise command to define f(x) explicitly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post, and use the checkmark to "accept" the answer to your question that you think best answers it.

Comment: @djp see: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/597/standard-greeting-comments

Comment: Please provide code in your question, not screenshots. See the formatting help provided when editing your question for hints on how to have code formatted as code (spoiler: indent every line by four spaces). This will make helping you much easier.

Answer (score 5):

```
myfunc[x_] := Piecewise[{{c x^2 + 2 x, x <= 2}, {x^3 - c x, True}}];
lim1 = Limit[myfunc[x], x -> 2, Direction -> -1]
lim2 = Limit[myfunc[x], x -> 2, Direction -> 1]
sol = c /. First@Solve[{lim1 == lim2}, c]

 (*2/3*)

Plot[myfunc[x] /. c -> sol, {x, 1, 3}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point[{2, myfunc[2] /. c -> sol}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Once I get the value of C how do i use the Piecewise command to define
>   f(x) explicitly

`f(x)` is already  defined. No need to redfine it. Just replace the `c` value found from solve each time you use the function.

Notice that the function is continuous at `x=2` but not differentiable at `x=2` and Mathematica can tell that:

```
D[(myfunc[x] /. c -> sol), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How can I just plot myfunc[x] over the intervals 0<=x<=4 and 1.9<=x<=2.1.

Comment: @user27386  Changed the plot command above to change the limit of the plot. Like this `Plot[myfunc[x] /. c -> sol, {x, 0, 4}]` or `Plot[myfunc[x] /. c -> sol, {x, 1.9, 2.1}]` etc... but if you want to zoom in and out, it is very easy to make a manipulate and use a slider to change the zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve for `c`, given your `Limit`-conditions:

```
cc=Solve[
      Limit[myfunc[x], x->2, Direction->-1]
      ==Limit[myfunc[x], x->2, Direction->1], c]
(* {{c -> 2/3}} *)
```

and apply it (`myfunc[x]/.First@cc`) with the result

```
Piecewise[{{2*x + (2*x^2)/3, x < 2}, {(-2*x)/3 + x^3, x >= 2}}, 0]
```

**Hint:** If you define `myfunc` by directly using `Piecewise`, you can get rid of the impossible third case automatically introduced by the formatted (bracketed) input:

```
myfunc[x_]:=Piecewise[{{c x^2 + 2 x, x < 2}}, x^3 - c x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you got your two limits, you could just solve them like this:

```
sol = First@Solve[8 - 2 c == 4 (1 + c)]
(* c -> 2/3 *)
```

and then

```
myfuncC[x_] := myfunc[x] /. sol
```